# Replace Empty field by X on a positional file

Tags: bash, shell

I use bash script and i have a positional file like that :

```
ID(10c)   NAME(10c) CITY(10c) 
ID(10c)   NAME(10c) CITY(10c)
```

for Example if i have

```
123456    TOTO                   
123457              PARIS
```

I want this output :

```
123406    TOTO      XXXXX             
123407    XXXXX     PARIS
```

I need to implement this algorythm :

- id = id(0,4) + 0 + id(6)
- if name is blank replace name by XXXXX
- if city is blank replace city by XXXXX
- Write the generated line in temp file

What I have tried:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS="10 10 10"}{$ID = $1;$NAME = $2;$CITY = $3;$ID = substr($ID,1,4)0substr($ID,6);if ($NAME ~ /^\s*$/) $NAME = "XXXXX     ";if ($CITY ~ /^\s*$/) $CITY = "XXXXX     ";PRINT $ID$NAME$CITY}1' $FILEINPUT >> $FILEINPUT.tmp
```

Comment: are missing fields replaced by spaces? (fixed width records?) NAME and CITY may contain spaces?

Comment: Yes : ID(10char)   NAME(10char) CITY(10char) But if the fieds name or city are empty a need to add XXXXX just x5 not the lenght of the field NAME and CITY . They may contain empty spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`, you could say:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS="10 10 10"}{if ($2 ~ /^\s*$/) $2 = "XXXXX     "; if ($3 ~ /^\s*$/) $3 = "XXXXX     "}1' inputfile
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
123456     TOTO       XXXXX     
123457     XXXXX      PARIS
```

---

EDIT: As per your input, you could say:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS="10 10 10"}{if ($2 ~ /^\s*$/) $2 = "XXXXX     "; if ($3 ~ /^\s*$/) $3 = "XXXXX     "; $1=substr($1,1,4)0substr($1,6)}1' OFS='' inputfile
```

to get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you ! They not run :/ i have an infinite loop... you can see the conplete script on my topic .

Comment: @L.Quastana I'm not sure what your script is intended for.  The above command line would transform the given input into the desired output.

Comment: Ok , But in my $1 field i would to replace one char by 0 value like that : $1 = substr($1,1,7)0substr($1,9) but they not run .

Comment: @L.Quastana Please update your question instead.  It's tough to read the comments due to the lack of formatting options.

Comment: @L.Quastana See the `EDIT` above.

Answer (score 0):

split lines into fixed width fields and check if field is empty

```
while read ligne  
  do
  ID=$(echo $ligne | cut -c 1-10)
  NAME=$(echo $ligne | cut -c 12-21)
  CITY=$(echo $ligne | cut -c 23-33)

  if [ "$(echo $NAME | tr -d ' ')" == '' ]; then
    # replace NAME
    NAME="xxxxxx"
  fi
done
```